# Spring @Entity Annotation findById

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbctemplate

I have the below Student entity, trying to make a REST API for this.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<Course> enrolledCourses;

    public Student() {
        // default constructor
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

When using `@RestController`, I am able to do `@GetMapping("/api/students)` and the page returns all the student's JSON. However when I try `@GetMapping("/api/students/{id}")` and specify `@PathVariable` the page returns something but all the fields are null. Anyone know what's the problem?

EDIT:

```
@RestController
public class StudentRestController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/api/students")
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/students/{id}")
    public Student getStudentById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return studentService.getStudentById(id);
    }
}
```

The `StudentService` gets from the `StudentRepository` which gets from PostgreSQL database. But the `StudentRepository` here uses `JdbcTemplate` to fetch from database instead of extending `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`, I'm not sure if that might be the problem. I'm using code passed to me from my team. Here's the repo method `findById`, using `ResultSetExtractor` and `RowMapper`.

```
public Student findById(int id) {
        String selectSQL = "SELECT s.id as s_id, s.name as s_name, " + 
            "s.email as s_email, " +
            "c1.id as c1_id, c1.name as c1_name, c1.alias as c1_alias, " +
            "c2.id as c2_id, c2.name as c2_name, c2.alias as c2_alias," +
            "c3.id as c3_id, c3.name as c3_name, c3.alias as c3_alias," +
            "c4.id as c4_id, c4.name as c4_name, c4.alias as c4_alias " +
            "FROM students s " +
            "JOIN courses c1 ON s.course1_id = c1.id " +
            "JOIN courses c2 ON s.course2_id = c2.id " +
            "JOIN courses c3 ON s.course3_id = c3.id " +
            "JOIN courses c4 ON s.course4_id = c4.id " +
            "WHERE s.id = ?";

    return (Student) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(selectSQL, new Object[]{id},
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Student.class));
}
```

EDIT2:

I created a custom `StudentRowMapper` and `StudentResultSetExtractor`, now there's another error, `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: student, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(enrolled_courses)]`. Do I use `@OneToMany`?

EDIT3:

Using `@OneToMany` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code of your Spring webmvc controller class

Comment: Added the RestController.

Comment: what does this method has `studentService.getStudentById(id)`

Comment: Please provide the code of studentService.getStudentById(id);

Comment: Did you debug to see if the controller method gets the id right?

Comment: Added the repository method, might be the problem here.

Comment: Why in hell do you use SQL instead of using JPA? Just execute entityManager.find(Student.class, id), and you'll have your student. Your SQL doesn't make much sense, BTW.

Comment: @JBNizet I guess it's an attempt to load joined info as well.

Comment: Yes I agree that the SQL code is a mess, I probably wouldnt have done it this way... But I'm not sure if I should rewrite it.

Comment: JPQL queries are perfectly able to load the courses along with the student, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have renamed the bean property attributes in your sql with aliases like s_id for id ,s_name for name so you used use a custom row mapper to convert your results.

```
public class StudentRowMapper implements RowMapper
{
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Student student = new Customer();
        student.setId(rs.getInt("s_id"));
        student.setName(rs.getString("s_name"));
    //and so on
        return student;
    }

}

 return (Student) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(selectSQL, new Object[]{id},
            new StudentRowMapper(Student.class));
```

may be useful article 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Comment: I created a custom RowMapper and ResultSetExtractor, now there's another error, Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: student, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(enrolled_courses)]. Do I use @OneToMany?

Answer (score 1):

Your BeanPropertyRowMapper cannot find fields. You rename them in your SQL.
So BeanPropertyRowMapper tries to find field `id` but your query returns `s_id`
so nothing is set in the Student class.

Change SQL to return exactly the same column names as columns used in Student class.

Create a separate POJO instead of Student and add the fields you need. Check the POJO fields has corresponding column names in the SQL to be filled properly.